# How to handle minoccurs="0" when calling web services?

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a web service I am trying to call using a mainframe integration product (DataDirect Shadow z/Services), but my question is more of a general one.  I want to know how an element defined as minOccurs="0" is typically handled.  The operation on the 3rd party service I am calling has a complexType element where all of the elements within it are marked minOccurs="0".

**Example from WSDL**

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Request">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="startDate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="endDate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="requestId" type="tns:ObjectName"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="reasonCode" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="actionType" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="option" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="comments" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

The way this service works on the other end, if a value is passed to the service, *even if it is null or blank or default*, the value will be updated on the 3rd party system.  **I need a way to OMIT that element in the payload to the service**.  How is that generally handled?  I have tried using C# as a client for this service but the only thing I can find that they provide is the `Specified` suffixed variable for non-primitive types, but didn't find a way to omit primitive ones.  If I was calling this web service by simply `POST`ing the SOAP message to the 3rd party server I could simply omit the XML for the value I did not want to pass, but I am just wondering how different web service client implementations handle this.

If it helps I believe the 3rd party is using Apache Axis and said they could omit the optional arguments.

Answer (score 0):

When you tried POSTing with the xml part relating to the default/optional arg missing, did you notice any update for that arg at the server (apache axis) side? If you did, then it may be a problem with how the server-side logic had been implemented for that WSDL (not strictly respecting the contract/schema as defined by the WSDL).

Comment: I haven't actually tried POSTing the request yet, I was just thinking that would work in general.  Problem is though that I won't be able to do that in code.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked with 3rd Party Web Services that require you to pass a value for all available tags that has a `Specified` parameter. You can pass pretty much anything in there as long as you set the `Specified=false`.

Usually you'll get your primitive types to have the `Specified` tag as well as handling types such as `int, bool, double` is a problem since they've got default values defined and not setting the `Specified` tag will cause those values to default to their default defined value.